# Translating a word problem mathematically.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I really hope I get my point across.

I want to translate the following into a mathematical statement:

> suppose at time $t=0$, I have an amount $x(0)$ in the bank. At time $t$ I would like to make a payment, (depending on current status of my account) that cannot be more than $A$ and no less than $B$.

Is it possible to write it using $\max$ and $\min$ functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about $\max(x,A) = A$ and $\min(x, B) = B$? You can also say $B \leq x \leq A$.